# What does clearQueue in jQuery do?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I was reading the code for AutoScroll plugin @ 
http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/08/an-ultra-lightweight-autoscroll-to-top-jquery-plugin/

There you will find

```
var t = jq('<div class="'+ops.styleClass+'"></div>')
```

then after some code

```
t.clearQueue().fadeOut(ops.hideDuration || 200);
```

What do clearQueue is doing here ? Or simply what do clearQueuein jQuery does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will cancel any queued items (usually animations) that have not yet run.

If there's a current animation (for example) taking place, it is not affected. But any queued items will not execute.

In this example, the `height` animation will continue, but the queued `.fadeOut()` will not occur.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/sXnVj/

```
$('div')
    .animate({height: 500},1000)
    .fadeOut();

$('div').clearQueue();
​
```

Or take a situation where an item has been queued, but never dequeued. Any subsequent queued items will never execute, unless you clear the queue.

Here, the `.fadeOut()` will not happen:

```
$('div').queue(function() {});

$('div').fadeOut(2000);
```

But here it will:

```
$('div').queue(function() {});

$('div').clearQueue().fadeOut(2000);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Description: Remove from the queue all items that have not yet been run.

http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

That call should be pretty equivalent to

```
t.stop(true,true).fadeOut(ops.hideDuration || 200);
```

The only difference here is that `clearQueue` will remove **all** functions from a (function) queue, whereas `.stop()` will only effect `fx methods`.

Comment: Please tell me what is in the queue in `t.clearQueue`. or may be my question is not correct!!

Answer (score 0):

It clears the queue of function calls pending to execute, that is functions that have been invoked but have not yet executed at this point. Check this for more information:

http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Answer (score 0):

It's not part of the AutoScroll plugin, he is just using it from the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

Comment: yes i know that. But my question was `what does clearQueue do`. and now after @jAndy's answer my question is At the time of `t.clearQueue` what is in the queue? Which queue it is talking about?

Comment: That's what the link to the jQuery API was for, it describes what `.clearQueue` does. patrick dw already answered with an excellent example anyway